# Ask a question about measurable function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that:

1) For a fixed $x$, $f(x,y)$ is a measurable function of $y$ and
2) For a fixed $y$, $f(x,y)$ is a continuous function of $x$.

Prove that for a function $g(y)$ that is measurable on $\mathbb{R}$, we have that $f(g(y),y)$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}$.

I can prove that f(x,y)is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^2$,but I don't know how to prove this problem?

For f(x,y) is just measurable on $\mathbb{R}^2$,is the result still right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You say that you know how to prove that $f(x,y)$ is measurable. Also $y\mapsto (g(y),y)$ is measurable, right? What happens when you take the composition?